# Большой класс

Tags: c#

Считается ли класс большим, если он реализует 10 интерфейсов?
Но при этом, в итоге должна остаться вся функциональность.
Кол-во строк порядка 1.5 тысячи.
Данный класс является базовым для других.

Comment: - Функциональность, простите, чего в итоге должна остаться?
- 10 интерфейсов -- это не страшно, хотя может быть поводом задуматься. Другое дело, что иногда без этого не обойтись:

        public class List<T> :
            IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList,
            ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>,
            IReadOnlyCollection<T>,
            IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable

Comment: Это реестр с работой базы данных. В нем есть интерфейсы по применению фильтров, перебора значений, оповещений при изменении выделенной записи и другие. 
Меня просто интересует не перегружен ли он..хотя это наверное абстрактный вопрос.

Comment: @Костя

- Выложите посмотреть имена интерфейсов и хотя бы по примеру нетривиального метода из каждого интерфейса.

- Возможно, у вас получился `God Object,` который логично будет распилить. То есть, применение фильтров и перебор значений, скажем, еще укладываются в одну сущность, а вот оповещение кого-то там -- это уже точно другая область ответственности.

Comment: class BaseGrid : BaseWindow, IIterableGrid, IGridNotify, 
        IFilterWindow, IWorspace, ISubFilterContainer, ISupportNavigator,
        ISupportLoadBehavior, IAccessable, IGroupViewBehavior, IBaseGridObservable, IBaseGridObserver

IIterableGrid - реализует интерфейс по перебору строк и получении значений из строки
IGridNotify - не совсем удачное имя, это костыльный интерфейс, обновляет в строке видимые значения.

Comment: IIterableGrid - реализует интерфейс по перебору строк и получении значений из строки
IGridNotify - не совсем удачное имя, это костыльный интерфейс, обновляет в строке видимые значения.
IFilterWindow - может принимать доп. фильтры к основному запросу
ISubFilterContainer - хранит доп. фильтра
IAccessable - реализует получение и добавление модели доступа к реестру
ISupportNavigator - навигация в реестре, перелистывает страницы.
ISupportLoadBehavior - может, грузить данные
IBaseGridObservable, IBaseGridObserver - могут наблюдатели подключатся, когда меняется выделенная запись

Comment: @Костя: хм, неужели не получается разделить на части? Фильтрация и загрузка данных, например, вроде хотят разделиться...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как я понимаю, ваш `BaseGrid` — это `View` с некоторыми лишними зависимостями, от которых неплохо бы избавиться. Если вы не против потенциально деструктивных изменений, то развязать это дело можно примерно следующим образом`:`

- Намного удобнее, если модель реализует `IObservable,` а все виды являются ее подписчиками. Таким образом модель `push'ит` эвенты, **в ответ на которые** происходит обновления вида. Делать какой-то вид `Observable` (да еще и `Observer'ом!`), на мой взгляд, не очень классное решение.

> Сюда же видимо идет и `IGridNotify,` от которого можно было бы избавиться, сделав модель `Observable`.

- `ISupportNavigator` (с семантикой `IViewWithPages`) кажется мне хорошим интерфейсом для `View.`
- `ISupportLoadBehavior` на самом деле является **деталью реализации.** То есть, вы можете сказать вашему `View` *"загрузи мне вот такую-то модель"* и вам, в принципе, должно быть все равно, как этот `View` осуществит ее загрузку. А дальше уже разные поведения вида можно моделировать, например, с помощью сабклассинга типа `BulkLoadingView` и `ViewThatLoadsEverythingSequentially.`
- `IAccessible` — это либо неудачный выбор имени для интерфейса, либо результат нехорошего дизайна`:`

> - Обычно примерное назначение интерфейса должно быть понятно из его названия. Круто, если для каких-то уже известных сущностей вы сможете с большой степенью точности сказать, попадают ли они под слово, описывающее интерфейс, или нет. Вот, например, `List<string>` — он `IAccessible` или нет?
> - Если `IAccessible` нужен только для того, чтобы сообщить вашему виду, что он нацепляется на такую-то модель, то выкиньте этот интерфейс, передавайте модель (`IModel / Model / SpecificModel`) через конструктор и заинкапсулируйте логику работы с моделью внутри вашего класса.

- Задачи `IFilterWindow` и `ISubFilterContainer,` на мой взгляд, более изящно решаются с помощью прокси-моделей`:`

> - То есть, вместо того, чтобы делать логику фильтрации частью вида, вы можете на каждый запрос-фильтр создавать новую фильтрующую модель и нацеплять ее на ваш вид. Такой подход проще тестируется и обладает гораздо меньшей связностью.
> - `IFilteringModel(IModel, FilterQuery, AdditionalFilterQueries) : IModel`
> - Вот, скажем, сколько изменений в вашем текущем подходе придется внести, чтобы делать фильтрацию на уровне базы данных, а не на клиентской части? В варианте с `IFilteringModel` нужно будет всего лишь добавить еще одну прокси-модель.

- Не смог сообразить, что такое `IWorspace` (`IWorkspace?`), и, собственно, зачем он здесь нужен.
- Про `IGroupViewBehavior` тоже ничего не могу сказать, хотя из названия кажется, что можно его оставить.
- `IIterableGrid` кажется не самым плохим интерфейсом, но, если подумать, то он него можно и **даже нужно** избавиться:

> - Вот, предположим, у вас есть модель и есть ее некоторый вид. Вы писали-писали *какой-то* код и в некоторый момент времени у вас появилось желание проитерироваться по вашему `Grid'у` и узнать, какие элементы в нем сейчас отображаются. Почему не спросить эти элементы **напрямую у модели,** а не у какого-то ее вида?
> - Лично я вижу две возможные причины, почему вы могли захотеть спрашивать данные напрямую у `View` — либо между элементами `View` и элементами модели нет взаимно-однозначного соответствия, либо `View` нацепил поверх модели какую-то дополнительную информацию, к которой хочется получить доступ, но которой нет в модели.
> - Первый кейс решается с помощью прокси-моделей (см. выше). Второй кейс также легко решается переносом всей информации, которую нацеплял `View`, в модель — ту же самую или расширенную (включающую в себя все данные из старой модели `+` что-то еще). Опять же, в этом варианте мы резко расширяем свое возможности в плане тестирования.

- Если все вышенаписанное *соединить вместе,* то получится вот такой вот дизайн (комментарии и критика привествуются)`:`

  ```
  public class BaseGrid : BaseWindow, IModelObserver,
                          ISupportNavigator [IViewWithPages],
                          IGroupViewBehavior(???), IWorkspace(???)
  {
      public BaseGrid(IModel model, ...) { ... }
  }

  public interface IModel : IModelObservable { ... }

  public interface IFilteringModel: IModel { ... }
  ```

Comment: Отлично, отделение представления от модели должно [помочь] распутать клубок. Я сразу и не сообразил, что класс, имплементирующий интерфейс `ISupportLoadBehavior`, может относиться ко View.

Comment: @VladD Ну, я тоже мог не угадать, хотя мне кажется, что здесь речь идет именно о всемогущем `View` в стиле `WinForms.`

Answer (score 4):

Если классу действительно никак "не обойтись" без всех этих интерфейсов и их, возможно, множественных реализациях, то можно разбить класс на несколько файлов. Ключевое слово **partial** вам в помощь.

А вообще не хорошо так раздувать классы. Возможно, ваш класс представляет из себя "кучу хлама", в которую вы просто-напросто свалили все, что у есть в приложении. Проверьте это. Ведь если это действительно так, то было бы целесообразно навести порядок, реализовать несколько классов, предназначенных для разных целей.